# Sending multiple documents to sign DocuSign C#

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign API with c# and I'm using method to send a document to multiple recipients, asking for the signature.

```
public string SendDocument(string FileName, string DocumentName, DocuSignRecipient[] Recipients,
            string EmailSubject = null)
{
    DocuSignParams Params = MakeParams();

    Params.Command = "send";

    Params.FileName = FileName;
    Params.DocumentName = DocumentName;
    Params.Recipients = Recipients;
    Params.EmailSubject = EmailSubject;

    DocuSignResponse Response = RunDocuSignApp(Params);

    if (!Response.Success)
        throw new Exception(Response.Message);

    return Response.EnvelopeId;
}
```

But, as you can see, the first parameter is a file, so I can't send multiple files at once.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: As per the API signature then you can't send multiple documents. You need to look for an alternative interface which can support for multiples documents to multiple recipients in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the C# SDK, you can do that.
I suggest you start by cloning our [C# example code](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp)
so you can see how it works.
The relevant code for your scenario looks like this: (but won't work without the nuget):

EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
envelopeDefinition.EmailSubject = "Please sign this document";
Document doc1 = new Document();
Document doc2 = new Document();

```
        String doc1b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

        doc1.DocumentBase64 = doc1b64;
        doc1.Name = "Lorem Ipsum"; // can be different from actual file name
        doc1.FileExtension = "pdf";
        doc1.DocumentId = "3";

        // The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
        envelopeDefinition.Documents = new List<Document> { doc1, doc2 };
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use this.